# In present-day reality no-one actually uses classical Latin any more.Why can we use "Classical Latin uses the ablative" in present tense?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english, british-english, grammaticality-in-context

What is the difference between (a) and (b)

(a)"Classical Latin **uses** the ablative"

(b)"Classical Latin **used** the ablative"

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not anyone actually uses classical Latin today does not change the fact that classical Latin is still a thing which exists and uses the ablative. So the present tense is correct.